# Using beautiful soup4 and requests but I get the following 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get a specific href from an article using beautifulsoup4 and requests but it's not working. I watched some tutorials and it worked for them fine. I'm using it in a Django app and that may be the issue. heres my code.

```
url = "http://www.example.com/en_us"
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

article = soup.find_all("article")[:1]
tag = article.find_all("href")[0]

context = {
    "all_results": all_results,
    "tag": tag,   
}
```

I've also tried

```
article = soup.find_all("article")
tag = article.find_all("href")
```

but it's not working. What's the proper syntax. Any help or guidance is welcome

Comment: `href` is usually an attribute not element, and you can't use `find_all` to get HTML attributes, AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the `̀href` of the first `a` of the first `article` :

```
article = soup.find("article")
hrefAttr = article.find('a')['href']
```

or :

```
hrefAttr = soup.find("article").find('a')['href']
```

`find()` limits search to the first occurrence.

And you can't use `̀find` to search for attributes of a tag.

Use the tag as a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first `article` tag, you should use `soap.find('article')`.

see the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) for more.